# MikTeX doesn't produce pdf when I hit "r" after the first error

Tags: miktex, compiling

My apologies if this has been asked before — but I searched both on this site and online in general, and I couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere.

I recently reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9 on one of my computers. When I compile, I have a habit of hitting `r` for `\nonstopmode` after the very first error. Previously, after I do that, MiKTeX (or rather pdfLaTex that it runs) would still generate an output pdf file. Of course, the file would look weird, but then I can fix that one error, and compile again, and so on, and so forth …

But now, in this new installation, there's no output produced when I do that. Instead, after doing all the work it eventually stops and shows an error message "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed."

I'm sure there's an option for the compiler that controls this behavior, but I don't know what that option is. Could you help me please?

**EDIT:** Here's some additional info that maybe could help. In the "Tool Configuration" dialog of the "Typesetting" tab of "TexWorks Preferences", I have the following options for the `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` profile:

```
--pdf
--synctex=1
--clean
$fullname
```

Comment: Your chances to get help with the current level of provided information are very small. In general, I would not recommend having errors in the code as a normal situation. Tip: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I appreciate your feedback. I'm not a newbie to SE, although I'm mostly active on other SE sites, not here -- I'm only mentioning that to make a point that I know in general what is expected of a good question. But I'm not sure what else would help here. Could you please advise what additional information would help? My question is not about any particular code, but rather about MiKTeX compiler options.

Comment: I am no expert on compiler options either. Maybe you are in luck and someone around here dealt with a similar issue before. Still, I would provide a small but complete code example with a mistake on purpose. Then show the error message and state your compiler options so that others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sometimes, a PDF cannot be produced. So, without a minimal example of a case which demonstrates the problem, we can't know whether this is particular to your setup or specific to your code. If you tell TeX to carry on regardless of errors, it will **try** to do something by guessing what was intended. Even if it guesses wrong, this sometimes succeeds. But only sometimes. Other times, compilation fails because things are just too screwed up or screwed up in another way. So far, your question includes no evidence that ultimate failure is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: The profile you describe probably attempts to execute multiple binaries, but you have not shown the sequence of commands executed. Moreover, you have not said what happens if you run e.g. `pdflatex` only without trying `makeindex`/`xindy` or `bibtex`/`biber`.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to see the (incorrect) output file? Wouldn't it be faster to press `x` to abort and then fix the error?

Comment: `r` still works for me on miktex. But as @cfr wrote: there are errors that are so serious that they prevents the creation of a pdf and then miktex can't succeed, even more if you run more than one tool.

Comment: have you looked at the log file to see what other errors were found?  that is the only way to debug a failure like this.  i gave a talk on debugging latex at bachotex/tug 2017.  the slides are available at http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2017-pl/presentations/bbeeton-1-2017.pdf (the paper was published in tugboat 38:2, but that is accessible only to members.)

Comment: Specifically, instead of `r`, use the `x` option to immediately abort the compilation.  Then look at the end of the .log file to see what the error was.